# Flask CORS sometimes work and sometimes doesn't

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, tornado, flask-cors

I have a flask application deployed in a tornado WSGI container. The tornado server is hosted on `http://localhost:5000`. This entire thing is deployed using Nginx reverse proxy. The flask serves its endpoints to the tornado server through CORS:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
```

The flask application is deployed in the following manner:

```py
flask_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(app)
tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
    [   
        # tornado specific handlers,
        (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=flask_app))
    ], 
    log_function=log_function,                                      
    websocket_max_message_size=100 * 1024 * 1024)
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(
    tornado_app,
    max_buffer_size=1024 ** 3,
)
```

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```sh
upstream frontend {
    server localhost:5000;
}

gzip on;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml
           application/x-javascript application/xml
           text/javascript;

proxy_next_upstream error;

server {
    listen <server_ip>:80;
    server_name <server_hostname>;

    auth_basic "Administrator's Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    }
}
```

I am getting `CORS: Request did not succeed` errors for all the flask endpoints when I use Nginx reverse proxy. Without it, the tornado server at `localhost:5000` accepts all the flask routes. Sometimes, it works by itself and sometimes it doesn't. Mostly, it's the latter. I have also tried setting cors-specific headers in the Nginx config but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It took a lot of time to figure this out but I am happy to come up with a solution (in case anyone is finding). Actually, I didn't need to use `flask-CORS` anymore. In deployment, the origin was the same throughout i.e `<server_hostname>` or `<server_ip>`. Steps to the solution:

1. Removed the cors and config lines in the flask application
2. In my tornado application, I replaced the flask routes like so:

```py
http://localhost:5000/flask_app
# to
http://<server_hostname>/flask_app
```

3. If you have cors configured in Nginx, remove the corresponding `add_header` directives as well.